# how to use row_number() in oracle?

Tags: oracle, apache-spark

I have this query:

```
select ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) AS RNO, my_table) AS subQuery
```

I want to connect to 2 Databases - Postgres and Oracle with spark jdbc. When I insert this query to dtable option, for Postgres its works, but for oracle I am getting `Caused by: OracleDatabaseException: ORA-00923: FROM keyword not found where expected`

By reading oracle docs, I see that they support row_number, but I can't understand what I am doing wrong.

```
val reader = spark.read
      .format("jdbc")
      .option("url", "location")
      .option("dbtable", ("select ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) AS RNO, my_table) AS subQuery")
))....
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Oracle, the `FROM` clause is mandatory in a `SELECT` statement, so you cannot use `(SELECT NULL)` you would either want just `NULL`:

```sql
SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY NULL) AS RNO,
       my_table AS subQuery
FROM   some_table
```

or `(SELECT NULL FROM DUAL)`:

```sql
SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY (SELECT NULL FROM DUAL)) AS RNO,
       my_table AS subQuery
FROM   some_table
```

However, the latter seems pointless and will not work on PostgreSQL as it does not have a `DUAL` table. You could create a single-row read-only `DUAL` table in PostgreSQL but the first option works in both RDBMS so it seems like overkill.

*Note: Your query is syntactically invalid in both databases as you have an extra `)` after `my_table`.*

[Oracle fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/N_anAphd) [PostgreSQL fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/k0PN1na_)

Comment: but what in case that I want to select the RNO column with my all table content? like in this example: https://dbfiddle.uk/knFofHz0 in oracle i cant find a way.

Comment: @MTO, I am want to build sequential rank e.g 1,2,3.. in your last example they are (rno's) same. Thanks

Comment: @DavidZaltsman `select ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY aba, bbc) AS RNO, subQuery.* from some_table subQuery` [PostgreSQL fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/F_P1tZYb) [Oracle fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/lSF2i08E) (In Oracle it is mandatory to have: the table alias before the `*` when selecting other columns as well; no `AS` before the table alias; and, an `ORDER BY` clause in the `ROW_NUMBER` analytic function)

Answer (score 0):

In Oracle, omit `select` in `ORDER BY`:

```
SQL> select row_number() over (order by null) as rno from dual;

       RNO
----------
         1
```

You can't omit `order by` clause, though:

```
SQL> select row_number() over () as rno from dual;
select row_number() over () as rno from dual
       *
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-30485: missing ORDER BY expression in the window specification


SQL>
```

Comment: and this query will work on postgres? I will achieve the same result?

Comment: I don't use PostgreSQL; I wouldn't know. If I had to guess, I'd say YES.